# Start ajax request when other ajax request is running

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

In C# .NET it seems not to be possible to run 2 ajax request simultaneous. This is my Javascript code:

```
function startAjaxRequest1() {
    setTimeout(startAjaxRequest2, 2000);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/test.ashx/status",
        contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {},
        failure: function (response) {}
    });
}

function startAjaxRequest2() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/test2.ashx/statusupdate",
        contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {},
        failure: function (response) {}
    });
}
```

When Ajax request 1 is executing, request 2 (started after 2 seconds), will never start. When I remove request 1, request 2 is executed is performing well.

Is it not possible to start a second ajax request when another is buzzy?

UPDATE:

In fact, this is my first ajax request (send files to server). Maybe it has something to do with this. The second ajax request keeps requesting each 4 seconds untill $.ajax(options) hass succeeded and the inner Ajax request is started. From that time, second request stops requesting. If I remove the inner Ajax request, there is no problem.

```
var options = {};
    options.url = "/uploadGeoJsonFiles.ashx";
    options.type = "POST";
    options.data = data;
    options.contentType = false;
    options.processData = false;
    options.success = function (result) {

          $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "/dashboard.aspx/importGeoJsonData",
                data: jsonString,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {


                },
                failure: function (response) {



                }

            });

    };
    options.error = function (err) {

        showError(err.statusText);
    };

    $.ajax(options);
```

Comment: Works like a charm: https://jsfiddle.net/5jvL13vn/

Comment: Normally this should work. The problem is probably somewhere else. Does the opposite have the same issue? Aka a setTimeout for the first call inside the second. What happens if you remove the setTimeout? WIll both requests fire at the same time?

Comment: Do you see your second request called in your network tab? What's the http status?

Comment: The second ajax request only starts when ajax request 1 is finished for some reason...

Comment: This is the explanation: http://tech-journals.com/jonow/2011/10/22/the-downsides-of-asp-net-session-state. No solution I think, unless disabling session state but that's not possible in this case.